# Как применить условие к нескольким классам и id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть код

```
$(function() {
        var form = $("form");
        var tab = form.find(".tab");
        var current_index = 0;
        var len = tab.length;
        var back = $(".back");
        var next = $(".next");
        var submit = form.find("input[type=submit]");

        function show() {
            submit.toggle(current_index == len - 1);
            next.toggle(current_index < len - 1);
            back.toggle(current_index > 0);
            tab.hide().eq(current_index).show()
        }
        show();

        function audit(current_tab) {

            var elems = $(".required", current_tab);
            return [].every.call(elems, function(el, i) {
                var ok = el.value.trim();
                ok && +ok != 0 ? el.classList.remove("empty_field") :
                    el.classList.add("empty_field");
                return ok && ok != "0"
            });
        }


        next.on("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var current_tab = tab.eq(current_index);
            var required = audit(current_tab)
            if (required) {
                current_index++;
                show()
            }
        });
        back.on("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            current_index--;
            show()
        });
        form.on("input change", ".required", function(event) {
            var ok = this.value.trim();
            ok && ok != "0" && this.classList.remove("empty_field")
        })
        form.on("submit", function(event) {
            return audit(form)
        })
        submit.on("click", function(event) {
            return audit(form)
        })

    });
```

Как применить условие не только к .required, но еще и к нескольким другим (например #parent_cat_id, #category_id и .city-input если его value = 0,?

В действии http://plnkr.co/edit/qO8z7dk5FwruwzO2uAYf?p=preview

Спасибо.

Comment: Уточните что вы хотите.

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы производилась валидация некоторых полей при нажатии на "следующий шаг". В примере на первом шаге к выпадающим спискам применен класс .required, но к сожалению добавить его не в код не могу. Хотелось бы проверять их по #parent_cat_id и #category_id

Comment: обновил изначальную тему

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте метод `add` и добавьте нужные элементы

```
var elems = $(".required", current_tab).add('#parent_cat_id, #category_id');
var input = $('.city-input');
if (input.val() == 0)
  elems = elems.add(input);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Но если я добавляю в вашу конструкцию дополнительно .city-input

var elems = $(".required", current_tab).add('#parent_cat_id, #category_id, .city-input');

то на второй шаг не пускает (

Comment: Хотя там по-сути проверка должна быть по value не равно 0

Comment: Подскажите, как реализовать еще и такую проверку?

Comment: Я неверно рассудил, что добавив .city-input если его value = 0, то поле (city-input) будет подсвечиваться. Поэтому бессмысленный комментарий оставил. Не могу додуматься как добавить к конструкции если value = 0, чтобы осуществлялась проверка

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/qO8z7dk5FwruwzO2uAYf?p=preview

Comment: Почему-то не сработало 
http://plnkr.co/edit/qO8z7dk5FwruwzO2uAYf?p=preview

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82530/discussion-between-anton-shchyrov-and-wa-a).

Answer (score 3):

Еще один вариант множественных селекторов, это просто писать через запятую

```js
$('div, span').each((idx, el) => console.log(el.innerHTML));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Раз два</div>
<span>Три четыре</span>
```

Comment: У него первый селектор ищется в контексте `current_tab`

Comment: Ну, а кто сказал, что `#parent_cat_id и #category_id?` не в этом же табе? Гляньте его верстку, там они находятся в одном табе